# How do I do configuration if there's no Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly equivalent in DNX Core 5.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET 5 (1.0.0-beta6) project that, when I try to reference both DNXcore 5.0, and DNX 4.5.1, gives me interesting problems, like with this little snippet of code:

```
  public class DatabaseConfig
    {
        private static ResourceManager RM;
        ...

        static DatabaseConfig()
        {
            // Get a Resource Manager.
            RM = new ResourceManager("DatabaseConfig", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        }
```

How do I write the above so that I can configure my application both on DNX 4.5.1 and on DNXCORE 5.0?  Why is ResourceManager still valid but Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() is not?  Is there a single way to write the above code that is valid in both frameworks?  Or do I need to do some kind of `#if` magic stuff?

According to a video ["What's new in ASP.NET 5"](https://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/en-US/training-courses/what-s-new-with-asp-net-5-8478) on Microsoft Virtual Academy, apparently the Modern practice is not to use ResourceManager at all. Yet the class clearly still exists.

Should I configure via a ResourceManager? Or some other way?

Update:

If I need to have different code for DNXCORE, I can use `#if` like this:

```
   static DatabaseConfig() {
   #if DNX451
      //code here to configure in DNX 4.5.1 context
   #endif
   #if DNXCORE50

      //code here to configure in DNX Core 5.0 context

   #endif
}
```

Comment: Here is an approach to replace `GetExecutingAssembly`: http://forums.asp.net/t/2001385.aspx?Assembly+GetExecutingAssembly+core